# Create event with Microsoft-graph php-sdk

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I try to create event with php-sdk but setting start and end timezone not working.

```
$e = new Model\Event();
  $e->setSubject($subject);

$start = new Model\DateTimeTimeZone();
  $start->setDateTime($startDateTime);
  $start->setTimeZone($startTimeZone);

$e->setStart($start);
$e->setEnd($start);

$body = new Model\ItemBody();
  $body->setContentType(Model\BodyType::HTML);
  $body->setContent($content);

$e->setBody($body);
```

But the result event is every time in UTC.

I tried:

```
$e->setOriginalStartTimeZone($startTimeZone);
$e->setOriginalEndTimeZone($startTimeZone);
```

and adding a header:

```
Prefer: outlook.timezone="Pacific Standard Time"
```

But the result is same.

On top of that when I add

```
$e->setReminderMinutesBeforeStart(8);
$e->setIsReminderOn(true);
```

The remainder is disabled. If I don't include this code the reminder is enabled 15 minutes before the event.

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the value of `$startDateTime` and `$startTimeZone`?

Comment: Thanks for help. Please check this screen shot. I try the query form Graph explorer. https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16517518/54337841-d2c8d200-4638-11e9-8223-9b60dc19266a.png

Answer (score 2):

You're *setting* both the `dateTime` and the `timeZone` to `UTC`. I'm not sure what you are expecting to happen, but this *should* generate a new `event` using `UTC`.

When you specify time using the `Z` suffix you are, [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones), telling it "this is Coordinated Universal Time". It is the equivalent of setting the date/time offset to [`UTC -0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets#UTC%C2%B100:00,_Z):

> The time zone using UTC is sometimes denoted `UTC±00:00` or by the letter `Z`—a reference to the equivalent nautical time zone (GMT), which has been denoted by a `Z` since about 1950.

If you want to use "Pacific Standard Time" then you would want to use

```
$start = new Model\DateTimeTimeZone();
  $start->setDateTime("2019-03-11T21:01:57");
  $start->setTimeZone("Pacific Standard Time");
```

Although you might be able to simply use `-08:00` as the UTC offset (I'm not experienced enough with the PHP SDK to know if this would work off the top of my head, but I imagine it would):

```
$start = new Model\DateTimeTimeZone();
  $start->setDateTime("2019-03-11T21:01:57-08:00");
```